# avoid repeating column condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

lets assume I have the following df -

```
students = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("amit",),
        ("amit",),
        ("itay",),
    ],
    ["student"],
)
```

I want to create a lot of columns based on the value in student column.
I know for sure that I might have just 2 values on this data frame.

example:

```
students = students.withColumn(
    "address", f.when(f.col("student") == "amit", f.lit("berlin")).otherwise(f.lit("paris"))
).withColumn(
    "studies", f.when(f.col("student") == "amit", f.lit("CS")).otherwise(f.lit("physics"))
).withColumn(
    "age", f.when(f.col("student") == "amit", f.lit("25")).otherwise(f.lit("27"))
)
```

can I do it cleaner without repeating all the time `f.when(f.col("student") == "amit"` or to create this columns together? any suggestions can be good.

Comment: Maybe create a data structure(dictionary) to hold new column names & it's value in order, eg { 'address':['berlin','paris'],'studies':['cs','physics']...} and loop through it in `select` stmt

Comment: nice idea,
how can I loop with select?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of 3-tuples with all the information that's necessary to create your columns:

```py
values = [
    ("address", "berlin", "paris"),
    ("studies", "CS", "physics"),
    ("age", "25", "27")
]
```

Then, you can create your spark columns by iterating over `values`:

```py
cols = [
    f.when(f.col('student') == "amit", f.lit(val1))
        .otherwise(f.lit(val2)).alias(col_name) 
            for (col_name, val1, val2) in values
]
students.select("*", *cols).show()
```

```
+-------+-------+-------+---+
|student|address|studies|age|
+-------+-------+-------+---+
|   amit| berlin|     CS| 25|
|   amit| berlin|     CS| 25|
|   itay|  paris|physics| 27|
+-------+-------+-------+---+
```